# Multiple join statements not returning the expected result

Tags: sql, join

I have to write a query with the following requirements:

> The query should return a list of all
>   entry values for a customer named
>   “Steve” and for each date shown (if
>   available) the most recent status detail for 
>   that date.

**Customer Table**

```
CustomerID | CustomerName
1          |    Steve
2          |    John
```

**Entry Table**

```
CustomerID | EntryDate | EntryValue 
 1         | 5/4/2010  |    200.0  
 1         | 4/4/2010  |    100.0  
 1         | 3/4/2010  |    150.0
 1         | 2/4/2010  |    170.0
 2         | 5/4/2010  |    220.0
```

**Status Table**

```
CustomerID | StatusDate | Detail
1          | 5/28/2010  | D
1          | 4/24/2010  | S
1          | 4/5/2010   | P
1          | 2/28/2010  | A
```

The expected output is:

```
CustomerName |   Date    |   OrderCost |   Detail 
  Steve      | 5/4/2010  |    200.0    |  S
  Steve      | 4/4/2010  |    100.0    |  A
  Steve      | 3/4/2010  |    75.0     |  A
  Steve      | 3/4/2010  |    75.0     |  <null>
```

I think that the expected output may be wrong and it should actually be:

```
CustomerName |   Date    |   OrderCost |   Detail 
  Steve      | 5/4/2010  |    200.0    |  S
  Steve      | 4/4/2010  |    100.0    |  A
  Steve      | 3/4/2010  |    150.0     |  A
  Steve      | 2/4/2010  |    170.0     |  <null>
```

Given the requirement, I don't understand why the 3/4/2010 date would occur twice and the second time it would have a  Detail. I wrote the following query:

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT  Customers.CustomerName, Entries.EntryDate, Entries.EntryValue, Status.Detail
FROM   Customers
    INNER JOIN Entries ON Customers.CustomerID = Entries.CustomerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status ON Status.CustomerID = Customers.CustomersID AND Status.StatusDate <= Entries.EntryDate
WHERE (Customers.CustomerName = 'Steve')
```

The result of my query is this:

```
CustomerName| EntryDate |   EntryValue |   Detail
Steve      |  5/4/2010 |    200.00  |   S
Steve      |  5/4/2010 |    200.00  |   P
Steve      |  5/4/2010 |    200.00  |   A
Steve      |  4/4/2010 |    100.00  |   A
Steve      |  3/4/2010 |    150.00  |   A
Steve      |  2/4/2010 |    170.00  |   NULL
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong here? I can't figure it out...

**Update**
I've changed the order to an entry so it doesn't confuse us that much.

Comment: Is this homework? If so maybe the given output is just an example and is not exactly what you need to get. I don't see any entry in the order table with an OrderCost of 75.0.

Comment: @Bertrand: the status detail is incorrect for the order on 5/4/2010 in the OP's output. There are 3 rows returned, each with different status detail, rather than one row with status detail of "shipped."

Comment: @Mattt, I'll check my output... I copied a lot of this stuff by hand so I might have made a typo.

Comment: The two entries for `Steve, 3/4/2010` in the expected output give the total of `150.00` for the `OrderCost` column, which is in accordance with the Entry Table, but it is still unclear why the sum should be split like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting more results than you expect because the second JOIN condition is satisfied by many rows in the statuses table (e.g. There are 3 statusDates earlier than 5/4 so this date appears 3 times in the result set).

You need to JOIN statuses table, but get only one match (the latest). This can be done in several ways, AFAIK usually with a sub query. I think your case is rather complicated - I used a temp table. Hope it helps... (I currently don't have a DB to test this on, hopefully there are no silly syntax errors).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;

CREATE TABLE temp AS  -- This temp table is basically the result set you got
 (SELECT c.CustomerName, e.EntryDate, e.EntryValue, s.Detail, s.StatusDate
  FROM Customers c
    INNER JOIN Entires e ON c.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status s ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomersID
                    AND s.StatusDate <= e.EntryDate
  WHERE (c.CustomerName = 'Steve')
 );

SELECT t.CustomerName, t.EntryDate, t.EntryValue, t.Detail
FROM temp t
WHERE t.StatusDate = (SELECT MAX(t2.StatusDate) 
                      FROM temp t2 
                      WHERE t2.EntryDate = t.EntryDate);
```

<del>To refrain from creating a temp table I believe this will work (please try and do let me know!)</del>

```
SELECT t.CustomerName, t.EntryDate, t.EntryValue, t.Detail
FROM (SELECT c.CustomerName, e.EntryDate, e.EntryValue, s.Detail, s.StatusDate
      FROM Customers c
      INNER JOIN Entries e ON c.CustomerID = e.CustomerID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Status s ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomersID
                      AND s.StatusDate <= e.EntryDate
      WHERE c.CustomerName = 'Steve') AS t
WHERE t.StatusDate = (SELECT MAX(t2.StatusDate)
                      FROM temp t2
                      WHERE t2.EntryDate = t.EntryDate);
```

Comment: is there a way to use the one query as an input to anther query (i.e. avoiding the creation of a temporary table)?

Comment: @Lirik Yes, I think that's always an option - just keep in mind that if there is a lot of data the subqueries tend to make it slooow. I will edit to add an option with no temp table.

Comment: I tried it but there was an error with the Select Statement: "Invalid column name 'EntryDate'"... I was able to get Richar's query to work tho (with a minor modification).

Comment: Correct - I was hasty with my edit (hence the strikethrough on the second part of the answer now).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get the status.
Use TOP 1 for SQL Server or LIMIT 1 for SQLite/MySQL

SQL Server / SyBase

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Entries.EntryDate, Entries.EntryValue,
   (SELECT top 1 Status.Detail From Status
    where Status.CustomerID = Customers.CustomersID AND Status.StatusDate <= Entries.EntryDate
    order by Status.StatusDate desc)
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN Entries ON Customers.CustomerID = Entries.CustomerID
WHERE (Customers.CustomerName = 'Steve')
```

MySQL / SQLite

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Entries.EntryDate, Entries.EntryValue,
   (SELECT Status.Detail From Status
    where Status.CustomerID = Customers.CustomersID AND Status.StatusDate <= Entries.EntryDate
    order by Status.StatusDate desc
    limit 1)
FROM   Customers
INNER JOIN Entries ON Customers.CustomerID = Entries.CustomerID
WHERE (Customers.CustomerName = 'Steve')
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the status date come after the order date? Something like:

```
SELECT  Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderCost, Status.Detail
FROM   Customers
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status ON Status.CustomerID = Customers.CustomersID 
WHERE Customers.CustomerName = 'Steve' AND Status.StatusDate >= Orders.OrderDate
```

Also, the `CustomerID` in the `Status` table seems a bit strange as it's usually orders that have a status, not the customer. Shouldn't the status table have an `OrderID` field?

Comment: with regard to the Status/OrderID: I had to change the names of the columns, tables and the data a bit because the info is proprietary... I tried to come up with reasonable alternatives, but I apologize if they're not all that great. Otherwise, the current structure is an accurate representation of the actual db structure.

Comment: I should probably come up with better names, but the "Order Dates" are actually after the "Status Dates"... if it's an issue, then I'll come up with better names.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is wrong. The last row should be for the date 2/4/2010. Also, their order costs are not right either. 2/4/2010 should be returning null, because there is no matching status.

Comment: I've updated the tables a bit (changed the names so it's less confusing)... I still can't figure out how to construct my query tho.