# SQL query for maximum date

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I asked [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280452/multiple-join-statements-not-returning-the-expected-result) and I got some really good answers, but I'm trying to make the query without making a temporary table. I believe it can be done, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have two tables and I want to get the latest status for each entry, where the status date is less than or equal to the entry date.

**Entries Table (Entry):**

```
  UserID   | EntryDate  
 ----------------------
    1      |  5/4/2010  
    1      |  4/4/2010  
    1      |  3/4/2010  
    1      |  2/4/2010  
    2      |  5/4/2010
    2      |  4/4/2010
```

**Entry Status Table (Status):**

```
  UserID   | StatusDate  | Detail
  -------------------------------
    1      |  5/28/2010  |  D-1
    1      |  4/24/2010  |  D-2
    1      |  4/5/2010   |  D-3
    1      |  2/28/2010  |  D-4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
UserID | EntryDate | Detail
---------------------------
  1    | 5/4/2010  |  D-2
  1    | 4/4/2010  |  D-4
  1    | 3/4/2010  |  D-4
  1    | 2/4/2010  | <NULL>
```

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280452/multiple-join-statements-not-returning-the-expected-result) you can see my effort and the related answers, but I've narrowed down the issue in order to simplify the problem.

I tried to do something like this (but I know I must be horribly off):

```
         SELECT E.EntryDate, 
                S.Detail, 
                MAX(S.StatusDate) AS MaxStatusDate
           FROM Entry AS E 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Status AS S ON E.EntryDate >= S.StatusDate
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple join statements not returning the expected result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280452/multiple-join-statements-not-returning-the-expected-result).  Don't post duplicates, correct your original question if you mean to simplify it.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Would you write a new answer to a question asked yesterday?  Where would you see the question?

Comment: @Andomar: Activity, like editing, bumps the question into visibility

Comment: @OMG Ponies, activity bumps the question up in visibility? is that a new feature? I don't recall it being the case before... I tried it on one of my older (unanswered questions) and I didn't see the question move up at all.

Comment: The functionality existed for as long as I've been here - activity bumps questions under the "interesting" tab, which is what you see when you go to stackoverflow.com, or click the logo.  While not explicit, the functionality is listed in the FAQ, under "what if I don't get a good answer": http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
SELECT E.UserID
    , E.EntryDate
    , (SELECT TOP 1 Detail
       FROM Status AS S
       WHERE S.UserID = E.UserID
       AND S.StatusDate <= E.EntryDate
       ORDER BY S.StatusDate DESC)
FROM Entry AS E
```

If your database doesn't support `TOP` or for performance reasons you would prefer to avoid the `ORDER BY` you could try something like:

```
SELECT E.UserID
    , E.EntryDate
    , (SELECT S1.Detail
       FROM Status AS S1
       WHERE S1.UserID = E.UserID
       AND S1.StatusDate = (SELECT MAX(S2.StatusDate)
                            FROM Status AS S2
                            WHERE S2.UserID = E.UserID
                            AND S2.StatusDate <= E.EntryDate))
FROM Entry AS E
```

Comment: Suffix with LIMIT 1 rather than SELECT TOP 1 might work with MySQL, et al.  Would need to test that though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a universal way to do it, but in some SQL dialects, you can use TOP or LIMIT in a subquery to get the value from a column in the first matching record, based on a sort (ORDER BY) in another column.

For instance...

```
SELECT
  Entry.*,
  ( SELECT TOP 1 
      Status.Detail
    FROM Status
    WHERE
      Entry.UserID = Status.UserID AND
      Entry.EntryDate >= Status.StatusDate
    ORDER BY
      Entry.EntryDate
  ) As StatusDetail
```

Answer (score 1):

The `row_number` way, for databases that support it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY e.UserId, e.EntryDate
                    ORDER BY s.StatusDate desc) as rn
        ,       *
        FROM    Entry e
        INNER JOIN    
                Status s
        ON      s.UserID = e.UserID
                AND s.StatusDate <= e.EntryDate
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  e.UserID,
  e.EntryDate,
  s.Detail
FROM Entry e
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM Status) u
    ON e.UserID = u.UserID
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      e.UserID,
      e.EntryDate,
      MAX(s.StatusDate) AS StatusDate
    FROM Entry e
      INNER JOIN Status s
        ON e.UserID = s.UserID AND e.EntryDate >= s.StatusDate
    GROUP BY e.UserID, e.EntryDate
  ) sd
    ON e.UserID = sd.UserID AND e.EntryDate = sd.EntryDate
  LEFT JOIN Status s
    ON sd.UserID = s.UserID AND sd.StatusDate = s.StatusDate
```

The list of distinct users is used to filter out those users in `Entry` that are not represented in `Status`.

The resulting set is then joined with a derived table that contains maximum status date values that correspond to the entry dates.

Finally the `Status` table is joined again, this time to get the detail info.

The last two joins are left joins, so the result set will contain all rows from `Entry` for every user that is found in `Status`, and the inner join guarantees that there will be none for all the others.